# How to reference static classes in Actionscript 3 and to push object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cc

a.push({TYPE:"App", TITLE:"Hello World", DESC:"", logo:"static/image.jpg", screen:"assets/Apps_Full_Screen_Images/static_image.png"});

Error i'm getting:
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "assets/Apps_Full_Screen_Images/static_image.png" to Class.

Comment: I don't think you're showing the relevant line that would be throwing that error

Comment: The only code you've shown is that you are pushing an object into a what is likely an array. Where is the code that generates the error? The error is telling you that you cannot convert a String into Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add an external image and use it inside and array one has to add an asset to the Flash Library first and then generate a .swc file or add it to action script library in order for internal class to be created by flash automatically

very good article about this issue here
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-an-external-library-in-your-flash-projects--active-8759

Let me know if this was helpful. Thanks!